# recvfrom() not blocking

Tags: c, sockets

For some reason my recvfrom() function for sockets is not blocking on my server code like it is supposed to.  I am making a basic UDP server to create a rolling session key system.

What am I doing wrong here?  It continues on after this line (before i put the (n < 1)) and was crashing.  I am pretty sure recvfrom() is supposed to stop the execution of the program until it gets something from the client...

```
    int sockfd, portNumber;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, from;
    int n;

    // Invalid arguments
    if (argc < 2)
        exit(0);
    else if (atoi(argv[1]) > 65535 || atoi(argv[1]) < 1)
        exit(0);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
    {
        printf("Error opening socket.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    // Taken from reference
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portNumber = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portNumber);
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    {
        printf("ERROR on binding.\n");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(0);
    }

    // Get initial session key request
    int fromlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &fromlen);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        printf("Error in receiving.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not an error, you just encountered a non-blocking socket.

Comment: You are creating a stream socket and binding it, but you aren't doing a listen or accept.

Comment: this is udp...i don't think we are supposed to use a listen or accept?

Comment: we are creating a reliable udp socket system for my assignment

Comment: No you're not.  A stream socket is a *TCP* socket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use a stream socket for UDP;

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

What you mean to do is probably;

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

Trying to do `recvfrom` on an unconnected stream socket will most likely return immediately with an error. Next time, you may want to check `errno` for a hint.

Comment: as mentioned above, if you use SOCK_STREAM you will have to listen and accept incoming connection. Then you can use recvfrom on them.

Comment: Thanks!  What a silly mistake, it's late...haha and I am new to sockets :P  I really appreciate it and I am sure I will be back with more help needed xD